# Secant method with two ODE's of degree 2 - matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

$$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}-r\left(\frac{d\phi}{dt}\right)^2=G\cos\alpha-g\frac{R^2}{r^2}$$
$$r\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}+2\frac{dr}{dt}\frac{d\phi}{dt}=G\sin\alpha$$

The two ODE's above are given. I have written them as 4 ODE's of degree one and solved the equation with ODE45.

I've plotted the graph and now I want to find where the equation intersects with the horizontal line $y=1$. I want to use the secant method becuase then i do not have to calculate the derivative of my equation. Normally I would just take: "my equation" = 1, but how do I do it in this case when I got two equations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you have converted from your polar coordinates to x-y coordinates.

In such a case, let `y` be the vector of $y$ values at each time step $t_i$. To find where $y$ is close to $1$, simply do the following:

```
[mn,idx] = min(abs(y-1));
```

This gives you the minimum absolute distance as well as the index of the element, stored in `idx`. You can then interpolate from the neighboring indices in whichever way you'd like.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. (You will need to subtract 1 from your vector, because the function finds the zero crossing.index is supposed to be t vector in your case)

```
function [ out ] = VectorZero( index, vector )

out=[];
for i=1:length(index)-1

if(vector(i)*vector(i+1)<0)
    out=[out (index(i+1)*abs(vector(i))+index(i)*abs(vector(i+1)))/(abs(vector(i))+abs(vector(i+1)))];
end

if(vector(i)==0)
    out=[out index(i)];
end
end
```

I have written a few functions that find the index of min/max in a vector, finds the index of a value in a vector etc. Matlab doesn't seem to have a default function for things. Or maybe I didn't look hard enough.

Comment: You didn't try looking at the documentation for the functions named, not surprisingly, `min` and `max`?